# mLocationClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I have a problem using the Google Play location services. I was trying to follow http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html more or less. However Eclipse tells me that it cannot resolve my LocationClient. My code looks like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this); 


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    mLocationClient.connect();
}
```

I got a feeling, that the google-play-services library is not referenced proper, but when I got to the properties of my project there is a green check mark next to it. If you need more code let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the `mLocationClient` field?

Comment: It does sounds like a library issue. Make sure you have current version as well. Can you access anything else in the library? Location client should be under com.google.android.gms.location. If you can import that, it should work.

Comment: @NiekHaarman I don't think I did. Do I need to? How should I do this?

Comment: @sihrc I imported com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient without any error.

Comment: Where did you declare the variable? Try declaring it locally first to see if that works. If you've made recent changes to library paths and things, do what bstar55 says below

Comment: Also, does it say it can't resolve LocationClient, or mLocationClient

Comment: Ok I added private LocationClient mLocationClient; to the Activity, this seems to solve the error. Now is it right, that I declared the variable right in the beginning of my activity or should I do it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close and reopen your project.

Clean and rebuild your project.

Make sure you've added the correct imports to your  activity class.

Make sure you have private LocationClient mLocationClient; defined in your activity.

Comment: @Axel Glad to hear it!  I figured it start with the most broad (Eclipse issues) and work down to the more specific.

Comment: Oh sorry the ellipsis was not about your answer but first my rather mediocre question and second the fact that the examples on the Android page are that full of mistakes ;-)