# App with google play location services crashes on launch

Tags: java, android

After solving [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004471/mlocationclient-cannot-be-resolved) yesterday there are no syntax errors anymore in my code. However when I launch my app on my phone it immediately crashes. I'm not sure where the error comes from and I think it's too much code if I post everything, so I will first post the logcat and if someone can narrow the error down I will post the corresponding section of the code.

```
06-03 19:18:34.288: D/AndroidRuntime(22511): Shutting down VM

06-03 19:18:34.288: W/dalvikvm(22511): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41532ba8)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511): Process: com.axelfiedler.stayup, PID: 22511

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.axelfiedler.stayup/com.axelfiedler.stayup.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff.bT(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.a(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$c.bT(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at com.axelfiedler.stayup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:223)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

06-03 19:18:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(22511):    ... 11 more

06-03 19:19:56.736: D/AndroidRuntime(23049): Shutting down VM

06-03 19:19:56.736: W/dalvikvm(23049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41532ba8)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049): Process: com.axelfiedler.stayup, PID: 23049

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.axelfiedler.stayup/com.axelfiedler.stayup.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff.bT(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.a(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$c.bT(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at com.axelfiedler.stayup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:223)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

06-03 19:19:56.736: E/AndroidRuntime(23049):    ... 11 more
```

EDIT: This is how I call the connect() function inside onCreate()

```
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

Comment: the error clearly says you are not connected to the location client and you have to connect to it

Comment: Ok I think the part that I don't how to do, is the "and wait for on connected to be called" I added some code above, maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line: `Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.`

I think you're requesting updates before the location client is really connected.
When you call `locationClient.connect()` you have to wait the answer on `onConnected()`
which is a method you must override.

EDIT:
I see the problem in your updated question.
You have to call
`mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();`
inside `onConnected()`.

In your Activity or Fragment, add `implements ConnectionCallbacks`,
and override the methods `onConnected()` and `onDisconnected()`.

Good luck.

Comment: I added the function onConnected(), but how do I proper wait for an answer? I was thinking about some if-statement, but this doesn't work and seems not to be the way to go.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. Simply put `mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();` inside `onConnected()`. You don't have to do more so this method is called automatically when the connection is established.